# Bootstrap sass primary button text color

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

Hi how can I make the color #0ab3af have white text on a button I am using sass, I have set the primary color of the theme to this color but the button text color stays dark, Thanks

Comment: What about adding class .text-light to the button? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/colors/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the only problem with that is I will have to add that class to all buttons, I was hoping to set the text color for the primary color button throughout the web app, thanks

Comment: Why not just re-defining the btn class an incorporate '.text-light' to it? That will style all buttons in the app.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to bootstrap coming from tailwind, how would I do that in sass? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In `/app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss`:

```
.btn {
  background: <some-dark-color>;
  color: white; // Or any other light color.
}
```

Then add any new button with class `btn` and you should be good to go.